# Single finger scroll for Webpage - what technology? working example?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, web, scroll

**Setup:**

I have a website that is hosted locally on a Desktop Computer, I have a touchscreen hooked up to that Desktop. The website is viewed on the touchscreen using Firefox.

**Requirements:**

- Enable one-finger scrolling for my website from the touchscreen.
- It should behave exactly the way iPhone's one-finger scroll currently works.
- It only needs to work in Firefox.

**Questions:**

- What is the best technology to use in this case? (JQuery/Javascript/CSS?)
- Can you provide a working example/solution for me?

*Thanks very much.*

Comment: I'm pretty sure that touch scrolling is something that is implemented at the driver level, NOT content level.

Comment: Touch scrolling is basically the equivalent of doing the same single-finger touch scroll motion with your mouse, I believe... therefore shouldn't this be doable with something like capturing mouse events, aka normal web technology stuff?

Comment: How are you currently scrolling through webpages on the touchscreen in question?

Comment: @couzzi: There is a button on the side of the page to press to "scroll up" or "scroll down". They scroll up or down the page an incremented amount when pressed. This is done with Javascript, in case you were wondering.

Comment: What research have you yourself done on this? Have you contacted the manufacturer of the device to see if it supports touch scrolling events presented as mouse or other event types in javascript? Who makes the screen? What have *you* already tried?
Also, it was _not cool_ to downvote that guy who gave an (albeit naieve) answer. Downvoting new users is not a good way to encourage them...

Comment: The problem is that your touchpad does not natively support scrolling. The only way I could think to hack this is to track mouse movement while mousedown and scroll accordingly, but this is going to trigger on anyone clicking on your page. Most likely there is 0 way to tell if the user is using a trackpad instead of a mouse, so this isn't a very good solution. The best solution is to use a touchscreen, not a touchpad.

Comment: @S. Byrne: I've looked for a solution, but haven't found anything to solve my problem. I've looked at JQuery, CSS, Javascript, and more scrolling solutions. Problem is that they're usually made for mobile devices and have specialty code that only works on those types of platforms.

As far as downvoting the guy who said "I don't know, but I think HTML5," he definitely deserved the downvote. I even commented to let him know why I was downvoting. Maybe next time he'll take the time to really contribute to our community rather than using his unchecked stream of consciousness as an answer.

Comment: @CODe, forgive the back-and-forth, but what makes this screen a touchscreen? Does it only respond to `tap` and not `drag`? Also, the button on the side of the screen — is this exclusive to the page? If you drag the page like you would on iOs, does anything happen at all?

Just to clarify, RE: other comments — touch**screen* or touch**pad**?

Comment: @couzzi: Yeah, it looks like this may require more investigation on my part. This is kind of what I needed to know, since I didn't know the touchscreen capability depends on the screen itself and how it works. Didn't factor that portion in, I assumed it would basically just convert touch to mouse clicks. *Definitely screen, not pad*

Comment: As a quick test of whether or not `touch` events work (my money is on yes), navigate to [this iScroll demo page](http://lab.cubiq.org/iscroll/examples/simple/) on your device. More on iScroll 4 [here](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4).

Comment: @couzzi: Well, the touchscreen is installed in a mobile vehicle. I doubt I'll get to test anytime in the next few days. :(  Although, that iScroll library you linked may do the trick... :D

Comment: Hmm. that sounds interesting. Please respond with your findings. Would love to know more!

Comment: @couzzi: I shall, if your solution works I'll be back to pester you to make an answer out of it so I can accept. ;)

Comment: @SByrne: BTW, I understand the need to break new users in slowly, but he will never make meaningful contributions here if he continually posts answers like he posted. He needs to understand that answers like what he posted aren't answers, aren't going to be useful to anyone, and are only going to waste his time writing them and our time reading them. That is what the downvoting system is for, and I did take the time to write a nice comment saying that, while his answer was not useful, I appreciate the attempt. He deleted his answer, so my comment went with it, but take that for what you will.

Comment: @Code - fair enough, agreee to disagree.
So anyway, who makes the device in question?

Comment: @couzzi: Your solution worked, the iScroll library did the trick. I had someone with access to the touch screen try the example on the screen, and it worked exactly as I need and expected. Post that, and I'll gladly accept it as the answer.

Comment: @SByrne: Still not sure, I won't have access to it, myself, for a few days. I did have someone with access test couzzi's solution and it worked though, so case closed for me. I do appreciate the help and time spent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The 'iScoll' library is archived. For posterity see:

https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll [archived/read-only]
https://web.archive.org/web/20170515081250/http://iscrolljs.com/
https://web.archive.org/web/20180726185738/http://lab.cubiq.org/iscroll/examples/simple/

#### As of 18/5/2021 all <del>links</del> below 404.

---

For iOS-style scrolling on touch-aware devices (works great on desktop, too) <del>[iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4)</del> is a great solution.

Point the touch-device in question to this demo url : <del>http://lab.cubiq.org/iscroll/examples/simple/</del>

Features Include:

- Pinch / Zoom
- Pull up/down to refresh
- Improved speed and momentum
- Snap to element
- Customizable scrollbars

-Via the <del>[iScroll 4 docs](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4)</del>

Comment: The library has been archived by its owner: https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll
This answer has been updated with links to archive.org snapshots and the corresponding [archived] Github repo.

Answer (score 3):

Ill let you work out the nuances, but something like this gives you an idea

```
$(function(){

    var dragYStart;
    var dragScrollStart;
    $(window).one('mousedown',startDrag);

function startDrag(e){
    dragYStart = e.pageY;
    dragScrollStart = $(window).scrollTop();
    $(window).on('mousemove',drag);
    $(window).one('mouseup',stopDrag);
}
function stopDrag(e){
    $(window).off('mousemove',drag);
    $(window).one('mousedown',startDrag);
}
function drag(e){
    var delta = dragYStart - e.pageY;
    $(window).scrollTop(dragScrollStart + delta);
}

});
```

[see example](http://jsfiddle.net/DWjkW/)

Comment: This works great except for one small problem. The lists that are needing to be scrolled through are HUGE, so the feature of sliding and letting go to get a long, continous scroll is very important. That's something that this code doesn't have. When you let your finger go, it stops scrolling immediately.

Comment: See my new answer, think I found an out-of-the-box solution for you.

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE... found this this morning. this is probably exactly what you want

http://zynga.github.com/scroller/

Comment: Hey Adam, thanks for the update, tried this library but it unfortunately didn't work. :(  +1 for adding a new solution that may work for someone else though!

Answer (score -2):

use "mine" js plugin
I also have swipe event handler :D
http://hoangminhdat.com/myLab/dragScrollJS/

It doesn't work on handheld device, but work great on desktop, it's also very simple

I made it :D